# Remove \dotfill where \rule sits in particular lines/rows within \longtable environment

Tags: longtable

How could I replace `\dotfill` with `\rule{3em}{.6pt}` in some particular lines/rows?

[image: remove dotfill with rule]

..so it would look like this:

```
Item A ................ xxxxx
Item B ................ xxxxx
                        ----- +
Item C ................ xxxxx
Item D ................ xxxxx
                        ----- -
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{5cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}@{}}
Item A & xxxxx \\
Item B & xxxxx \\
& \rule{3em}{.6pt} $+$ \\ % remove \dotfill here
Item C & xxxxx \\
Item D & xxxxx \\
& \rule{3em}{.6pt} $-$  % remove \dotfill here
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand well what you want, use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` for the empty cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put something invisible in the cells, so that there is no room for `\dotfill` to insert dots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{5cm}<{\dotfill}@{}l@{}}
Item A & xxxxx \\
Item B & xxxxx \\
\hspace*{5cm}& \rule{3em}{.6pt} $+$ \\ % remove \dotfill here
Item C & xxxxx \\
Item D & xxxxx \\
\hspace*{5cm}& \rule{3em}{.6pt} $-$  % remove \dotfill here
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.. really smart trick!  `\rule{5cm}{0pt}` Perfect!

Comment: Yes, `\hspace*{5cm}` is simpler..

Comment: @guest_5758 Maybe the space is safer then the rule. Who knows which pdf viewer might have problems with a 0pt rule...

Comment: how to align `\longtable` to center (just the table, not the content)? I've put an `[c]` after `\begin{longtable}` but didn't work.

Comment: @guest_5758 Your table is already centred -- but you don't see it, because your second column `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}` is so big, it takes all the remaining space of the line -> If you want it centred, make the second column smaller.

Comment: Great! I changed `-5cm` to `-10cm` in second column like so: `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-10cm}`. The greater the number (`-10cm`, `-15cm` etc), the further `longtable` move to the right.

Comment: @guest_5758 Please see my edited code, simply let latex decide what's the best width for the column and don't try to do it manually.

Comment: thank you. I didn't realize that by simply removing `{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}` would solve the problem.

Comment: @guest_5758 Not removing `{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}`, but replacing `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}` with `l`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`, so the `\dotfill` will not be inserted. I also added a trick for raising the rule to the height of the operation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\operation}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
  \check@mathfonts
  \rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.3pt]{3em}{.6pt} $#1$
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{5cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}@{}}
Item A & xxxxx \\
Item B & xxxxx \\
\operation{+}  \\
Item C & xxxxx \\
Item D & xxxxx \\
\operation{-}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for raising the rule to the height of the operation symbol.